# How to join a List of string with a custom widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of strings and a custom stateless widget i want to add my custom widget after each string and show them all like one string in screen. I want to achieve something like this. the numbers in between should be my custom widget.

[image]

write now i get this result with my code.

[image]

code:

```
 customArabicText(BuildContext context) {
   TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 22);
   List<Widget> widgets = [];

for (var i = 0; i < responceOfFutureBuilder.data.length; i++) {
  number = arabicTextList[i].number.toString().toPersianDigit();
  //_calcLastLineEnd(context, arabicTextList[i].arabicText);
  final quranTextSize = calcTextSize(arabicTextList[i].arabicText, textStyle);

    widgets.add(
      SelectableText(
        
        quranTextSpecificSuraList[i].arabicText.replaceFirst(
            GetBismillah(
                quranTextArabic: quranTextSpecificSuraList[i].quranTextArabic,
                suraNumber: quranTextSpecificSuraList[i].suraNumber),
            ""),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
        scrollPhysics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        enableInteractiveSelection: true,
        textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.parent,
      ),
    );


  widgets.add(MyCustomWidget(text: "$number"));

}
return Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: Wrap(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
    spacing: 5,
    children: widgets,
  ),
);
```

}

my Build Method:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return Container(
    child: customArabicText(context),
);

}
```

in this code i receive a list of string from server side and with the help of for loop i loop through each element in the list and add each element in another list with my custom widget, so the new list looks like this.

```
[0]: string1
[1]: myCustomWidget
[2]: string2
[3]: myCustomWidget
[4]: string3
[5]: myCustomWidget
[6]: string4
[7]: myCustomWidget
[8]: string5
```

The join() method of list would be perfect, but the join() method accept just string i cannot pass my custom widget to a Join() method.

I achieve kind of solution with Wrap widget, but it does not done the job completely.
I am experimenting about 3 moths, but i did not find any solution.
I would be very appreciate it, if anybody can help me.

Comment: did you try `RichText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `RichText`. Here is a demo:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, watch) {
  

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: "Main text",
                children: [
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.book,
                        size: 42,
                        color: Colors.black38,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: "Main2 text",
                children: [
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.ac_unit,
                        size: 42,
                        color: Colors.black38,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Text("Next"),
        RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: "Main text",
                children: [
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.book,
                        size: 42,
                        color: Colors.black38,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: "Main2 text",
                children: [
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.ac_unit,
                        size: 42,
                        color: Colors.black38,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: yes i have tried the RichText, its not working.

Comment: do you want to produce  like  my answer, and what are using as end line, it that an image or an icon

Comment: no i did not produce it like your answer. It would be very very long, if i produce manually for every item in a list. i rather want to loop through a list of strings and put after every string my custom widget at the end, which is a stateless widget and then show them all as once, but not as column,Row or something else. I want to have all of them after each other.

Comment: are those widget will text and that logo, both `RichText` and `TextSpan` can have `children`, means you add as much long as you want , also it can be as list child, about your image i think only using `RichText`  and `WidgetSpan` can solve this

Comment: my friend thank you so much it was very helpful what you said i tried the richText in right way and i am now able to show the hole text and my widget as i wanted, but right now i have just 2 small problems. first the numbers in between the texts have wrong order, when i change the font size and second some texts at the end of the screen width cut off.

Comment: do you know how to set the numbers in between the text i mean in widgetSpan in correct order. I Have tried the directionality widget but no luck.

Comment: are you generating the list? else if you assing top to bottom , hope it will maintain order. also you can check `Directionality`

Comment: i add elements to the list in for loops. I also tried Directionality it happens nothing. I added my customWidget/numbers in between. If i just add text in a textspan children it works but in a widgetspan it did not. it looks like this with widgetspan.                                                        children: [
            WidgetSpan(
              alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
              child: Directionality(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  child: MyCustomWidget(number: numbers)),
              
            ),
          ],